# Git - fetch+merge on feature branch, rebase on master

Tags: git, version-control, github, dvcs

I have spent the last half hour reading up on `merge` vs `rebase` at
Stack Overflow. As I understand things, `rebase` is good because it maintains
linearity, but can be confusing for collaborators because it alters history.

So, would it be fair to deduce that

1. On the feature branch, use fetch+merge to maintain history and avoid
   confusion amongst collaborators. The clutter doesn't matter since it'll be
   deleted after pushing to master anyway.
2. On the master branch, use rebase to avoid clutter. Modifying history doesn't
   matter because the feature branch gets pushed out as a single commit.

Comment: there's a cool blogpost that basically gives you a guide on when to use which: http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/02/merge-vs-rebase/

Answer (score 1):

It mainly depends on your workflow and what role your branches play in that workflow.

As a rule of thumb:

- rebase is fine as long as you did not yes publish (i.e. push) you commits, yet, or if you are sure no one else is interested in your branch.
- an explicit merge is good when integrating some feature branch into another branch. In this case you want a descriptive merge commit.

In reality I almost always use `git pull --rebase`. The important part is setting the upstream to the correct remote branch, i.e.

- the branch you branched from before you pushed your work to a feature branch and
- your remote feature branch afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You rebase while you are on the 
[Topic Branch](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Topic-Branches)

```sh
# integrate the latest upstream changes into your "master"
git checkout master
git pull

# make sure that you're on your topic branch
git checkout my_topic

# do the rebase
git rebase master
```

Then when ready you can merge the topic branch into master

```
git checkout master
git merge my_topic
```